# Tabs Plugin - can't align the tabs to right (Asp.net)

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2010, css

I'm using the [Tabs Plugin](http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/jQuery-Tabs-Maintain-Selected-Tab-on-PostBack-in-ASPNet.aspx) and trying to align the tabs to right. I tried to put `dir="rtl"` and `style="text-align:right"` but it's not working.

Here's a photo:

[image]

This is the code:

```
   <%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="CS.aspx.cs" Inherits="CS" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
        <style type="text/css">
        body
        {
            font-family: Arial;
            font-size: 10pt;
        }
 ul.ui-tabs .ui-tabs-nav {
    text-align: right;
}

li.ui-tabs .ui-tabs-nav li {
    float: none;
    display: inline-block;
}
    </style>

</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.ui/1.8.9/jquery-ui.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<link href="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.ui/1.8.9/themes/start/jquery-ui.css"
    rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script type="text/javascript">
    var selected_tab = 1;
    $(function () {
        var tabs = $("#tabs").tabs({
            select: function (e, i) {
                selected_tab = i.index;
            }
        });
        selected_tab = $("[id$=selected_tab]").val() != "" ? parseInt($("[id$=selected_tab]").val()) : 0;
        tabs.tabs('select', selected_tab);
        $("form").submit(function () {
            $("[id$=selected_tab]").val(selected_tab);
        });
    });

</script>
<div id="tabs">
    <ul >
        <li><a href="#tabs-1">Tab 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tabs-2">Tab 2</a></li>

    </ul>
    <div id="tabs-1">
        Content 1
    </div>
    <div id="tabs-2">
        Content 2
    </div>

</div>
<asp:HiddenField ID="selected_tab" runat="server" />
<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Do PostBack" />
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using:

```
#tabs ul {
    text-align: right;
}

#tabs ul li {
    float: none;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Comment: @user2097810: Try the updated answer. Are you including this CSS before the plugins CSS?

Comment: yes, I placed it under the body css in the code above.
but it still in the left.

Comment: @user2097810: This worked on the plugin page you linked to. Can you update the question with what you've tried?